# Скобки и условие

Tags: cmd, bat

Наткнулся на непонятную реакцию на появление скобки в строке при использовании условия.

Код

```
call :print )a
goto :eof

:print
if ""=="" (
  echo %1
)
goto :eof
```

Ошибка:

> Непредвиденное появление a

В чем причина такого поведения?

Работающие варианты

- Обрамить кавычками вывод

  ```
  :print
  if ""=="" (
    echo "%1"
  )
  ```
- Убрать из условия скобки

  ```
  :print
  if ""=="" echo %1
  ```

Если я правильно понимаю, то скобка из выводимой строки интерпретируется как завершение оператора `if`. Зачем и как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря довольно странная логика у процедуры *print*:

> if "" == "" (...

В чем смысл такой проверки, непонятно. Возможно автор имел в виду:

```
:print
   if "%~1" equ "" echo:%~1
exit /b
```

По крайней мере здесь осуществляется проверка передачи процедуре аргумента и если таковой имеется, отправить этот аргумент в стандартный поток вывода и завершить процедуру (не прерывая работы самого командного сценария). А чтобы избежать ошибки "непредвиденного появления", можно, например, поступить так:

```
@echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "x=^)a"
    call:print !x!
  endlocal
exit /b

:print
  if "%~1" neq "" echo:%~1
exit /b
```

Задали расширенную обработку команд (***enabledelayedexpansion***), предварительно занесли данные в переменную, экранировав символ закрывающей скобки (***set "x=^)a"***), - в итоге видим в консоли то что нужно.

Comment: Приведен **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему. В реальном коде идет парсинг файла с проверкой условий. И значение переменной считывается из файла, так что заэкранировать не получится. Кроме того, я говорю, что проблема проявляется с многострочным if. Для однострочного ничего экранировать не нужно. Все и так работает

Comment: Хоть задача и не решена, но на исходный вопрос ответ получен.

Answer (score 1):

Это следствие прямой подстановки.

Оператор `Call` выполняет переход на метку `:print` с параметром `)a`.

После  перехода параметр `%1` имеет значение `)a`.

После его подстановки в очередной оператор

```
if ""=="" (
  echo %1
)
```

получается

```
if ""=="" (
  echo )a
)
```

Именно тут и выводится сообщение о несвоевременно нарисовавшемся символе.

Избежать этого без корректировки кода невозможно. Впрочем, две  возможные корректировки Вы уже указали.